# How can I add a row in UIPickerview

Tags: ios6, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView, the green button to add a new record in UIPickerView. I can add a new record, but it does not appear cause I can not change the number of rows in the component.

How can i add a record and a row in UIPickerView?

Thanks!

My UIPickerview:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B26lA9znN3CUSTdvX21kUF92MzA/edit?usp=sharing

EDITED: When I click on the green button, it displays a UIAlertView TextInput where I add a new value in my NSMutableArray, so the number of records changes. So when a ReloadAllComponents he not adds an extra row in UIPickerView because I already set an amount in numberOfRowsInComponent method.

Comment: Please post your codes on the data source and delegate of your picker view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you manage an NSMutableArray for your pickerview records. In this case you have to manage 3 methods to achive this:

**1. your green button handling method**

```
-(IBAction) greenbuttonPressed:(id)sender{
    // add new record to your NSMutableArray (mypickerviewrowsarray)

    [self.myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

}
```

**2. pickeview's datasource method, numberOfRowsInComponent**

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.mypickerviewrowsarray count];
}
```

**3. pickerview's delegate method, titleForRow**

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.mypickerviewrowsarray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

To do it right, make sure you set your pickerview's delegate, also you set your viewcontroller to implement the UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource.

Hope you can use this!

Comment: When I click on the green button, it displays a UIAlertView TextInput where I add a new value in my NSMutableArray, so the number of records changes. So when a ReloadAllComponents he not adds an extra row in UIPickerView because I already set an amount in numberOfRowsInComponent method.

Comment: If I understood well this means the reload should happen after alertview closes. So reloadAllComponents should be the last line in dismissWithClickedButtonIndex, AlertView's button handler. Have you tried this?  reloadAllComponents triggers the numberOfRowsInComponent also which should return now an incremented value.

Comment: Really reloadAllComponents reloads all the methods UIPickerView and for that reason I saw that the error was not in these methods. I was querying the database in ViewDidLoad methods and passing these queries for a MSMutableArray. In the method numberOfRowsInComponent I was returning the count of records. I solved the problem by making the query in numberOfRowsInComponent method, so the value will always be updated. In short, I was not performing the query again and so the number did not change. Excuse my bad english and thanks for help.